# React- Native Push Notification using FCM

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native-fcm

I need to send a token for users after registration is complete to the firebase and with that i need to deliver push notifications to users.

I was able to find proper tutorials for Android FCM Push Notification guides, but didnt find any working guides for react native. Someone please help me.

Answer (score 1):

React Native doesn't provide complete push notification solutions by itself. The official documentation doesn't even provide any integration guide for Android FCM.

Here are some popular community solutions:

- [wix/react-native-notifications](https://github.com/wix/react-native-notifications)
- [zo0r/react-native-push-notification](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification)
- [geektimecoil/react-native-onesignal](https://github.com/geektimecoil/react-native-onesignal)
- [Visual Studio App Center by Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/push/react-native-android)